# Is visiting family counted as Tourism in the new lockdown rules?

Tags: uk-citizens, czech-republic

Parts of the EU are bringing in new rules and going into lockdowns, most flights are continuing to run as normal but entry for tourism is suspended. The first to do this was Austria but other countries such as the Czech Rep have implemented some of the same rules.

> Austria's borders are open but the government has announced that travel for touristic purposes has been suspended

**Does visiting family members count as tourism in this case?**

For further context, I'm British and my civil partner is Czech, we had planned to visit her family over Christmas. CZ has currently implemented some of the same rules, declared a state of emergency for 30 days, Christmas markets banned, caps on event numbers, enforced hours for pubs and restaurants, etc. If they were to bring in the same stance on borders as Austria I assume that our visit would fall under the tourism category and therefore no longer be allowed? (We're both fully vaxxed and had 0 issues visiting for a week last month)

Comment: Austria does not prohibit entry for the purpose of tourism, but due to the lockdown and internal restrictions within Austria, tourism is de facto not possible. Not only for people coming from abroad, but also for people living in Austria. In the currently published information from the Czech authorities, I can also not find anything indicating that you as a vaccinated UK citizen should not be allowed to enter (for any purpose). Is that a new restriction and such a recent change that the information has not yet been updated, or where do you have your information from?

Comment: @Tor-Einar Jarnbjo The Re-open EU website https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/AUT/7011 seems to confirm the OP’s info: “In Austria, due to the current COVID-19 infection situation, a temporary lockdown is in effect from 22 November until 12 December at the latest. Travel to Austria for tourism will only be possible again after this period.”

Comment: @Traveller As I said, being a tourist *in* Austria is currently for most purposes de facto impossible because of the lockdown, but there are no entry restrictions particularly targetting tourists. You won't find a place to stay, since hotels are not allowed to accomodate you, you can't go out for something to eat and you are only allowed to leave your place of stay (which you don't have) for a limited number of reasons. One is outdoor sport activities, the skiing areas are open, and it is for example possible for people from the neighbouring countries to go skiing in Austria on a day trip.

Comment: @Traveller BTW, the information on 'Re-open EU' is often incomplete or very generic and does rarely go into details.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo since OP is visiting family and has a place to stay, are they affected by the lockdown?

Comment: @JonathanReez OP is going to Czechia and just used Austria as another example. In Austria, visiting friends or family is not allowed under the current lockdown rules. I am not 100% sure, but the restrictions in Czechia are much less severe, if you are vaccinated you have more or less unrestricted access to restaurants and hotels, and I don't think there are any restrictions for private gatherings or meetings with friends or family.